# Is there a term that would work in the UK that is equivalent to "Norwegian bachelor farmer"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, pejorative-language

Garrison Keillor introduced the term "Norwegian bachelor farmer," which is a bit like the male equivalent of *spinster*.

#### Is there a male equivalent of spinster that works in the UK?  I considered "confirmed bachelor" but rejected it as too neutral.

For reference, some definitions:

> Spinster: An unmarried woman, typically an older woman beyond the usual age for marriage.  In modern everyday English, *spinster* cannot be used to mean simply ‘unmarried woman’; it is now always a derogatory term, referring or alluding to a stereotype of an older woman who is unmarried, childless, prissy, and repressed. ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spinster))
>
> Norwegian bachelor farmers: A group of unmarried men who live on the outskirts of town and have little to no social skills or hygiene habits.  ([lakewobegon.wikia.com](http://lakewobegon.wikia.com/wiki/Norwegian_Bachelor_Farmers))
>
> confirmed: (of a person) firmly established in a particular habit, belief, or way of life and unlikely to change their ways.  *‘a confirmed bachelor’; ‘a confirmed teetotaller’* ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confirmed))

*Note: I don't care whether it's a single word, a phrase, an idiom -- anything is fine.  I have tentatively created a general term request tag for these situations.  If the moderators are not happy about the tag, I trust they will edit my tags and remove the new tag I made.*

Comment: The male equivalent of 'spinster' is 'bachelor' - and always has been. The 'Norwegian bachelor farmer with no social skills and poor hygiene' sounds like a tramp.

Comment: Is Keillor’s term in use *other than* describing bachelor farmers of Scandinavian descent living on the outskirts of the town of Lake Wobegone, where all the women are strong, all the men are good looking and all of the children are above average?

Comment: @NigelJ - I have never seen "bachelor" taken to include *elderly, prissy* or *repressed*. // Norwegian bachelor farmers don't sit around the coffee shop *all day*.  They also go home and do their farm work.

Comment: @Spagirl - It doesn't have to be widely used, to be widely understood.  The point is that although I think it's fairly well understood in the US, I doubt it's understood in the UK, and I'd like to find a term that *is* understood in the UK.  If the term proposed is also understood in the US, so much the better.

Comment: @aparente001 I didn’t ask if it was ‘widely used’. I asked *if* it was used outside of the context of Keillor’s creation. The definition on the Lake Wobegone wiki is particular to that setting so takes us no further. Having googled further it does seem to be used in talking about the difficulty of sustaining prairie-edge farming because women in the prairie states mostly don’t want to marry only isolated farms. It’s a term particular to a geographic, social and economic as well as marital state. It isn’t a straightforward equivalent of ‘spinster’.

Comment: @Spagirl - Well, *I* use it, and I still think the important things are that if it's used in conversation or writing in the US, most people will understand it, but my assumption is that that is not the case in the UK; and that my question still works, regardless of how well "Norwegian bachelor farmer" has made it into people's general active vocabulary.  I'm looking for something that can function in the UK as at least a partial equivalent, for males, for "spinster."  I included NBF as a colorful example of a term in that class that can be used, as far as I know, only in US English.

Comment: @aparente001 Well, I’m in the UK and would recognise it as a LW reference. If it was in a usage that made that not the likely meaning I would assume you meant to imply something like poorly integrated migrant.

Comment: All British members please think back over your colloquialisms! With what choice word does the common man in your part of UK disparage an awkward male who is "unlikely to find a wife"?

Comment: The term "chronic bachelor" is routinely used in India but I am not sure it's part of UK English. A distinctly disparaging tone is notable in this online article: http://www.alphamalenation.com/10-symptoms-of-chronic-bachelor/ All 3 answers to this Quora question also state that it is ***not*** a compliment: https://www.quora.com/in/What-is-the-practical-meaning-of-Chronic-Bachelor-1

Comment: Note too that according to Urban Dictionary, which seems to have its pulse on cunning euphemisms and what people ***really*** mean, "confirmed bachelor" is not really neutral but is either insinuating or pejorative: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=confirmed%20bachelor

Answer (score -1):

Just ‘single man’. Or ‘singleton’ if that’s not already out of fashion.

Singleton being a c. 80s-90s pop word as in ‘young singletons’ for example describing the young flat-sharers in the series ‘Friends’.

Norwegian bachelor farmer is apparently derogative. Spinster is neutral, as is single man.

Well, to be more precise, spinster is officially ‘neutral’ - you might see ‘married/spinster?’ on an official form. But it does carry a slightly sad, careworn feel. And it has become more ‘derogatory’ over time. A ‘spin-ster’ originates from ‘a woman who spins’ which is what women did, continually, for centuries, to make the enormous amount of yarn needed in households for cotton sheets etc, (which were then woven).

https://blogs.loc.gov/folklife/2017/03/from-thread-to-fabric-to-art/

Another option is ‘unmarried man’.

Comment: 'Spinster' is considered somewhat disparaging, definitely not neutral.

Comment: To me 'singleton' describes a person with no siblings, not necessarily an unmarried one.

Comment: Norwegian bachelor farmer is comedy; it's not "a term". :)

Comment: How do you get that *spinster* is neutral in 2018?  The premise of the whole question is that it isn't neutral; and I documented that assumption.

Comment: @Jelila Really, you should believe every etymology you read online. https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/life-in-the-1500s/

Comment: @Jelila - You're entitled to your opinion.  I don't know whether you'd be able to keep it open, but you could write your own question, as to whether *spinster* is neutral or has derogatory overtones.  Also, you're always welcome to propose a discussion on Chat.  But such a discussion is tangential here.